# CGAL : hausdorff distance bad alloc

Tags: c++, cgal

I am trying to use approximate_Hausdorff_distance on  CGAL::Surface_mesh_3 data structure meshes, but after +- 30 seconds of calculations i'm getting every time bad alloc . both meshes contains no more than 2k points

Code was taken from PMP example:

```
std::cout << "Approximated Hausdorff distance: "
          << CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::approximate_Hausdorff_distance
                <TAG>(mesh1, mesh2,
                CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::parameters::number_of_points_per_area_unit(4000))
          << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I replied you on the cgal-discuss mailing list, the problem is probably the paramater `PMP::parameters::number_of_points_per_area_unit(4000)`, as if your mesh has a huge area there will be many points generated. If that is not the case please [post a bug report](https://www.cgal.org/bug_report.html) so that we can reproduce and fix.

Comment: Thats will gonna post a sample tonigth

Comment: Call the area function for the first surface  and then multiply that with 4000 and you will see how many points will get generated to compute the closest point on the other surface  https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__measure__grp.html#ga7e6384810b305b9df283bbf94fd9fd20